# I wanna use this pie chart but how to I change background color from white to grey

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna use this pie chart but how to I change background color from white to grey (rgb(226, 226, 226)). Is it even possible? The pie chart is from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_google_pie_chart.

```
<html lang="en-US">
<body>

<h1>My Pie Chart</h1>

<div id="piechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Work', 8],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['TV', 4],
  ['Gym', 2],
  ['Sleep', 8]
]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {'title':'My Average Day', 'width':550, 'height':400};

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just added the backgroundcolor to the draw option `backgroundColor: { fill: "#e2e2e2" }`

```js
// Load google charts
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// Draw the chart and set the chart values
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
  ['Work', 8],
  ['Eat', 2],
  ['TV', 4],
  ['Gym', 2],
  ['Sleep', 8]
]);

  // Optional; add a title and set the width and height of the chart
  var options = {
    'title':'My Average Day', 
    'width':550, 
    'height':400,
    backgroundColor: { fill: "#e2e2e2" }
  };

  // Display the chart inside the <div> element with id="piechart"
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Pie Chart</h1>

<div id="piechart"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```